# How to convert database in English language and to view data in Hindi on web page load

Tags: php, html

I got stuck to the problem that my database is in English language and I want to view the data in Hindi while website is being load.

I don't want to use drop-down of language from which language has been converted, I only want to view data in Hindi font.

Comment: What it means, **my database is in English language** ? Are you storing data in english and want to show it in Hindi? If yes, then better to store it in Hindi language in database using database column collection attribute to **utf8_general_ci**.

Comment: Yes!! Can I convert the table in hindi using mysql

Comment: can I retrieve the data in english convert it into web using php

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the problem to store data in database into Hindi?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with PHP using **[Google's translate API.](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#php-install)**

```
<?php
// [START translate_quickstart]
// Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;
// Your Translate API key
$apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
// Instantiates a client
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'key' => $apiKey
]);
// Get your database text to translate
$text = 'Hello, world!';
// The target language - hindi -> hi
$target = 'hi';
// Translates some text into Russian
$translation = $translate->translate($text, [
    'target' => $target
]);
echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Translation: ' . $translation['text'];
// [END translate_quickstart]
return $translation;
```

**NOTE:** It's paid API